# Como faço mensagens em Javascript etc, quando logar aparecer um aviso?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql

Quero saber um código que quando a pessoa clicka em um button de OK para logar aparecer um aviso: “Você esta logado!”. Caso não logar aparecer um aviso: “Você não esta no sistema, digite corretamente suas informações de Acesso!”.

Teria como me ajudar?

Comment: Bem-vindo. O que você já tentou fazer? Poderia como colocar na pergunta para podermos avaliar e te ajudar melhor?

Comment: Isto pode ser feito com Javascript, jQuery, em conjunto com plugins visuais como sweetalert2 ou apenas Css. Dá uma procurada aqui mesmo no site que provavelmente encontrara material.

Answer (score 0):

Isso é muito relativo, há diversas formas de se fazer isso, depende do que está utilizando, se existe um banco de dados com o login e senha de usuários ou se quer utilizar somente JS, jQuery para se fazer isso.

Aí está um exemplo básico de aviso se a pessoa fez o login ou não, utilizando os dados nome = nome123 e senha = senha123, você pode ver o resultado:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>teste</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <style>
  #situacao{
   width:140px;
   height:70px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   margin-top: 40px;
   font-size: 16px;
  }
  .logado{
   background-color: #65ff00;
  }
  .nLogado{
   background-color: #cc1212;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <label> Nome: </label>
 <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome">
 <br>
 <label> Senha: </label>
 <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha">
 <br>
 <input type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" value="Logar">
 <div id="situacao"></div>
 <script>
  nome = "nome123";
  senha = "senha123";
  $("#enviar").click(function(){
    nomeDigitado = $("#nome").val();
    senhaDigitada = $("#senha").val();
    if(nomeDigitado == nome && senhaDigitada == senha){
     alert("Você está logado!");
     $("#situacao").html("Login com sucesso").addClass("logado");
     
    } else {
     alert("Você não esta no sistema, digite corretamente suas informações de Acesso!");
     $("#situacao").html("Login sem sucesso").addClass("nLogado");
    }
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: É bem isso mesmo! só que com banco de dados. bacana, deu pra ter uma ideia básica. Sou só Webdesigner, sei o básico de JS. mas vou criar um sistema com ajuda de outros devs back-end.  vlw! :)